# Not Null Contraint Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a specific requirement, one column cannot be set as null once some value is added.

On create its value is set as null by default
Once the value is added to the column, it cannot be empty.

For such a case I am trying to add check_constraints

```
add_check_constraint :user, 'registery_id != null', name: 'reg_id
```

This constraint is added on both insert and update calls.

Rail Version 7
Ruby 3.x

I want it only to be executed in the case of an update only.

Comment: Since you're using Rails, why not add a `before_update` callback that checks the value of `registry_id` can't change from a non-nil value to nil?

Comment: We update require skipping validation and callback, that why constraint needs to be added in DB

Comment: I don't believe add_check_constraint supports this use case. If it must be done at the data layer, I think this might call for a Postgres trigger that fires before update. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtrigger.html